# edit imported model data outside of GLTF loader (React App)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

I want to access the data of my imported model outside of the GLTF loader in my react app. In this case, I want to update the position of the model to slowly move along the z-axis while the animation function is being called.

I set a variable called plAr outside of all functions so that it would be globally accessible with 
`let plAr;` I also set `plAr = gltf.scene;` inside of the loader

however, I continuously get the error: " Cannot read property 'position' of undefined "

here is my code below:

```
import { GLTFLoader } from '../node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader';
import {OrbitControls } from '../node_modules/three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls';


var camera, scene, renderer;
// var geometry, material, mesh;
var mixer;
var clock = new THREE.Clock();
let Idle1;
let walk;
let attack;
let plAr;

init();
animate();

// Instantiate a loader
var loader = new GLTFLoader();

// Load a glTF resource
loader.load(
    // resource URL
    '/CHaracter mod1.glb',
    // called when the resource is loaded
    function ( gltf ) {
        mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(gltf.scene);
        plAr = gltf.scene;

    Idle1 = mixer.clipAction( gltf.animations[ 0 ] );
    walk = mixer.clipAction( gltf.animations[ 1 ] );
    attack = mixer.clipAction( gltf.animations[ 2 ]);

        scene.add( gltf.scene );
        gltf.scene.position.y = camera.position.y - .23;
        gltf.scene.position.x = camera.position.x;
        gltf.scene.position.z = camera.position.z - 2.2;
        gltf.scene.rotation.y = camera.rotation.y - 9.44;
        gltf.scene.scale.set(.02, .02, .02);

        walk.play();
        // gltf.animations; // Array<THREE.AnimationClip>
        // gltf.scene; // THREE.Scene
        // gltf.scenes; // Array<THREE.Scene>
        // gltf.cameras; // Array<THREE.Camera>
        // gltf.asset; // Object

    },
    // called while loading is progressing
    function ( xhr ) {

        console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );

    },
    // called when loading has errors
    function ( error ) {

        console.log( 'An error happened', error );

    }
);
var Xl = 0;
function init() {

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(90, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10);
    camera.position.z = 2;
    camera.position.y = .02;
    camera.position.x += -.03;
    camera.scale.z = 10;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var light1 = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xcccccc, 15, 2000, 2000, 2000);
    scene.add(light1);
    // geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.2, 0.2, 0.2);
    // material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

    // mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    // scene.add(mesh);

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
   // renderer.setClearColor( 0xFFFFFF );
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement)
        controls.enableDamping = true
        controls.dampingFactor = 0.25
        controls.enableZoom = false
Xl++;
if(Xl > 50){
//nothing
}
}

function animate() {
    var delta = clock.getDelta();

if ( mixer ) mixer.update( delta + .001);
plAr.position.z--;
//delta - .01 = twise as slow, + .01 = twice as fast
console.log("poop");
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
}
```

I know that declaring the variable with `let` works in js, but it seems different in react. 
If there is any help that I can get I would greatly appreciate it!! :) thanks in advance!

Comment: Anything hlps~ :)

Comment: @Mugen87 do you possibly the answer? :o I'm still having trouble. . .

Comment: nevermind I found the answer in another thread.